# Creating a User Interface Using Tkinter (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter

I looked through a tutorial on using Tkinter and saw that the following code:

```
>>> from Tkinter import *
>>> win=Tk()
```

This should produce a box with the title Tk and nothing else.  However, when I try this code out no such box appears.  I'm not getting any errors so I suspect it's working as intended.  Is it possible that there are additional steps I have to take if I'm on a mac?

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

w = Label(root, text="Hello, world!")
w.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This code runs automatically, however, in the guide it suggests that I use $ python hello1.py to run this code, which doesn't work.  Any ideas on why this might be?

However, this larger block does not work:

```
from Tkinter import *

class App:

    def __init__(self, master):

        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.button = Button(
            frame, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=frame.quit
            )
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.hi_there = Button(frame, text="Hello", command=self.say_hi)
        self.hi_there.pack(side=LEFT)

    def say_hi(self):
        print "hi there, everyone!"

root = Tk()

app = App(root)

root.mainloop()
root.destroy() # optional; see description below
```

The issue seems to have something to do with mainloop but I'm confused because at the same time that earlier block worked just fine with a root.mainloop() part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you run this code in IDLE?

Try above code in terminal (not in IDLE), then it will work as expected.

Comment: @Stopwatch, Testing Tkinter program in IDLE interactive session will not work. (Especially in Python 2.x.)

Comment: @StopWatch, In terminal, run `python` and then type command in `>>> ` prompt. (Not in shell).

Comment: @Stopwatch, Your updated codes (both shorter one and longer one) work for me.

Comment: Do you mean not in 'Python' shell?  Terminal boxes are called shells as well.

Comment: @Stopwatch, not in 'login' shell (such as sh, bash, ...).

Comment: Also, if I make a mistake (that is I try to go to the next line and it gives me a syntax error or otherwise) do I have to start typing out the code all over again?  Is there a better way in terminal?  P.S. I just read your response, thanks.  I believe I'm in the right box since I managed to get a little window with the words 'quit' up, though that button did nothing.

Comment: Another way: Save content of the code as `hello.py` ; Open terminal ; change directory (`cd`) to the directory where `hello.py` exist ; run the script: `python hello.py`.

Comment: It gives me the error "[Errno 2] No such file or directory" though I'm sure the directory is correct and the file exists.

Comment: @Stopwatch, You did not change to correct directory (where the file `hello.py` exist).

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to try and run it in Terminal you should follow the steps below

note- 'I find that running programs is Terminal that involve a tkinter Gui will often crash for me, however it may work for you'

```
1st - Open Terminal
2nd - Type 'python3.4' then press space bar once
3rd - Open a Finder window
4th - Go to where you saved your python file in the Finder window
5th - Once you have located the file in Finder, drag the file into the Terminal window
6th - Press enter, and enjoy your python program.
```

another note - 'It sounds like you need a better Python IDE, you should try out PyCharm it is a great Python IDE which you can code and run python programs in including tkinter stuff'

You can download PyCharm here https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/